# Having trouble correctly passing a variable in a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm working on a script that takes flac files in the format of ## ARTIST - TRACK.flac and pulls info from file name and tags appropriately.  I also have some flags for manual input of other info.  Problem is that the tracknames aren't getting tagged correctly.  It seems that it's stopping at the first white space regardless of my quoting technique which then throws off a bunch of other stuff as well. You'll notice that I echo out the trackname variable before tagging just to be sure that the variable is correct, which it is, but tagging is still off.  Thanks for the help (and any other pointers) in advance!

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# A flac tagging script 
#


while getopts :l:y:s:h opt ;
do
    case $opt in
        l) ALBUM="--set-tag=ALBUM=${OPTARG}"  ;;
        y) YEAR="--set-tag=YEAR=${OPTARG}";;
        s) SOURCE="--set-tag=SOURCE=${OPTARG}" ;;
        h) echo >&2 "tags flac files in folder with arguments: -r [artist] -l [album] -y [year] -s [source (cdr, promot, etc)]" ;;
    esac
   done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ "$1" ]
then
    for file
    do

        if [ -e "$file" ]
        then

            echo >&2 "Tagging file: "$file""
            filename=$(basename "$file")
            extension="${filename##*.}"
            filename="${filename%.*}"
            TRACKNAME="${filename##*- }"
            trackartist="${filename% -*}"
            TRACKNUMBER="${trackartist% *}"
            ARTIST="${trackartist##* }"

            echo  >&2 "$TRACKNAME"
            metaflac \
            --set-tag=ARTIST=$ARTIST\
            --set-tag=TITLE=$TRACKNAME \
            --set-tag=TRACKNUMBER="$TRACKNUMBER" "$ALBUM" "$YEAR" "$SOURCE"\
            "$file"



        else
            echo >&2 "No such file: "$1""
            exit 1
        fi
    done
else
  echo >&2 "Usage: "$(basename "$0")" INPUTFILE [...]"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Which space is it stopping at?

Comment: Can `$ARTIST` or `$TRACKNAME` contain spaces? Then you need quotes around them in the `--set-tag=` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

A quick rewrite

```
#!/bin/bash

tags=()

while getopts :l:y:s:h opt; do
    case $opt in
        l) tags+=( --set-tag=ALBUM="$OPTARG" ) ;;
        y) tags+=( --set-tag=YEAR="$OPTARG" ) ;;
        s) tags+=( --set-tag=SOURCE="$OPTARG" ) ;;
        h) echo >&2 "tags flac files in folder with arguments: -l [album] -y [year] -s [source (cdr, promot, etc)]" ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo >&2 "Usage: $(basename "$0") [options] INPUTFILE [...]"
    exit 1
fi

for file; do
    if ! [ -e "$file" ]; then
        echo >&2 "Error: No such file: $1"
        continue
    fi
    if ! [[ $(basename "$file") =~ ([0-9]+)" "(.+)" - "(.+)".flac"$ ]]; then
        echo >&2 "Error: can't parse filename: $file"
        continue
    fi

    echo >&2 "Tagging file: $file"
    metaflac "${tags[@]}" \
        --set-tag=ARTIST="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" \
        --set-tag=TITLE="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" \
        --set-tag=TRACKNUMBER="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" \
        "$file"
done
```

Notes:

- uses bash regex matching to simplify (I hope) filename parsing
- don't nest double quotes in double qoutes: the "nested" variable then becomes unquoted.
- don't use ALL_CAPS_VARS: one day you'll use `PATH=/my/file` and then wonder why your script is broken

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I was avoiding regex as I don't understand it yet, and this is a learning exercise.  I assume the bash_rematch lines up with the () in the if statement?  how is that conditional if statement passed to the metaflac line?  isit just held by bash by design?